# Function that returns different value for same parameter

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to create a function that returns a different value each time for the same parameter, and I'm not allowed to use static nor global variables.
Example: I have a function:

```
double exp(double x)
```

that increases the exponent of 'x' by 1 every time it's used:

```
1st time used: exp(2)=2, 2^1
2nd time used: exp(2)=4, 2^2
3rd time used: exp(2)=8, 2^3
```

then when I enter a different parameter, it resets the exponent:

```
4th time used: exp(3)=3, 3^1
5th time used: exp(3)=9, 3^2
6th time used: exp(7)=7, 7^1
```

I've tried to create a counter that counts how many times the function has been used for a certain number, but can't find a way to make the function remember the value of the counter. I also thought about recursion, but got nothing from that either.

I did manage to create the function with static variables, but since I'm not allowed to use them it's pointless...

```
double exp (double x) {
    static double n, d;
    static int i = 0;

    if(i == 0) {
        n = x;
        d = x;
    }

    if(x != n) {
        d = x;
        n = x;
        i = 0;
    }

    if(i > 0) {
        if(x == n) {
            d *= n;
        }
    }
    i++;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know what other limitations there are. Some other ideas that come to mind: write to a file, use a semaphore, etc...

Comment: Another limitation is that the caller sends only one parameter into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could have the caller provide the storage, instead of local static values?

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  double MyExp(double x, double *n, double *d, int *i)
    {
    if(!*i)
      {
      *n = x;
      *d = x;
      }

    if(x != *n)
      {
      *d = x;
      *n = x;
      *i = 0;
      }

    if(*i > 0)
      {
      if(x == *n)
        *d *= *n;
      }

    (*i)++;
    return *d;
    }

  int main()
    {
    int rCode = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    double values[] = {2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.0, 0.0};
    double *valuesPtr;
    double n, d;
    int i = 0;

    for(valuesPtr=values; *valuesPtr; ++valuesPtr)
      printf("  Value: %.0f\n", MyExp(*valuesPtr, &n, &d, &i));

    return(rCode);
    }
```

Comment: The caller sends only one parameter into the function tho.

Comment: What about using a struct? It would technically be a single parameter to the function

Comment: @greedisgood210, perhaps when you post a question in the future you could be more specific?  The number of parameters restriction was not mentioned in the question.  Also, you might find that answers are posted more readily when question code is a complete (but concise) compilable program.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer I'll keep that in mind, Thanks!